# elasticsearch | Querying document with list with term and terms not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a document where in I am storing a fields as follows. Field "community" is stored as list.

```
    {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "historic_participant1",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "community": [
              "Cortez",
              "Retail",
              "NetAtmo"
           ],
           "date": "2009-11-10T14:12:12",
           "memberID": 3,
           "validation": "valid",
           "dal_is_installed": true,
           "dal_is_flowing": true,
           "is_flowing_dal_tablet": true,
           "is_flowing_dal_computer": false,
           "is_flowing_dal_smartphone": true,
           "ss_is_installed": true,
           "ss_is_flowing": true,
           "ss_survey_responded_count": 5,
           "dal_mobile_activity_count": 5,
           "dal_tab_activity_count": 5,
           "dal_computer_activity_count": 5,
           "status": "verified"
        }
```

Here is the mapping of the field community as follows:

```
   "community": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
```

Now if I query the community with either term or terms as follows, I get my response as zero documents found. Can someone please help.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "community": {
        "value": "Retail"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also to mention, all the documents in the type stores the value of community as above mentioned. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you are using the [Standard Analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which lowercases your input.

Querying for retail (lowercase) will yield the expected result:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "community": {
        "value": "retail"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.15342641,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "community": [
            "Cortez",
            "Retail",
            "NetAtmo"
          ],
          "date": "2009-11-10T14:12:12",
          "memberID": 3,
          "validation": "valid",
          "dal_is_installed": true,
          "dal_is_flowing": true,
          "is_flowing_dal_tablet": true,
          "is_flowing_dal_computer": false,
          "is_flowing_dal_smartphone": true,
          "ss_is_installed": true,
          "ss_is_flowing": true,
          "ss_survey_responded_count": 5,
          "dal_mobile_activity_count": 5,
          "dal_tab_activity_count": 5,
          "dal_computer_activity_count": 5,
          "status": "verified"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You either need to lowercase your request, or set up a different analyzer.

Comment: But surprisingly, if you check this happens only for an array. If I use term for a simple String type, I have to provide the exact string in order to find the field. For example:  "term": {
      "census_region": {
        "value": "West"
      }
    }, it gives me the search result. However if I use value: west.. it does not.. Also if you notice.. in the query you provided, if I query with "retail" as all small, then the result fetched is perfect but it shows retail as "Retail". Any thoughts??

Comment: This is quite confusing for ES beginners, I agree. The returned result is NOT identical to the indexed data ES uses for its internal search. The returned result is always the original, unmodified document. As for the term "West", this might be too short for the analyzer to be parsed, be a stop-word or anything the like.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with `full-text` search on field `community`, tell elasticsearch to `match phrase` instead of your `term` query,

```
   "community": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
```

And query like,

```
POST http://yourEsHost:9200/INDEX/TYPE/_search
{
   "query": {
     "match_phrase": {
        "community": "Retail"
     }
    }
 }
```

### But

It will also give results when you query like,

```
POST http://yourEsHost:9200/INDEX/TYPE/_search
{
   "query": {
     "match_phrase": {
        "community": "Cortez Retail"
     }
    }
 }
```

**or**

```
POST http://yourEsHost:9200/INDEX/TYPE/_search
{
   "query": {
     "match_phrase": {
        "community": "Cortez Retail NetAtmo"
     }
    }
 }
```

**Reference**

[multi-value fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_multi_value_fields_2.html)